# Voice Input to Populate Edit Text in android?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am working on voice input in android. I used the sample from

> http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

And while testing on Xperia X10, I got the "Speak now" dialog but before I input some voice it gets closed. I am trying to implement voice search e.g. If voice input is James Bond then I want to populate the James in first name Edit Text and Bond in Last name Edit Text. Which will search in database for the name. But while trying to use the API Demo sample, its not working. May be I am missing something. Will anybody post any sample for voice input rather than ApiDemos sample.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following code for voice recognition. For a complete tutorial for voice recognition, **[Click Here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/)**.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* A very simple application to handle Voice Recognition intents
* and display the results
*/
public class VoiceRecognitionDemo extends Activity
{

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private ListView wordsList;

/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);

    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

    wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Disable button if no recognition service is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() == 0)
    {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }
}

/**
 * Handle the action of the button being clicked
 */
public void speakButtonClicked(View v)
{
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
}

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```