# How to activate speech to text with a button?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I would like to implement a button that when clicked would activate android's speech to text translator like the one provided by android's keyboard. Specifically, I would like a button that would have the app transcribe what the user is saying in real time, and record it word by word (real time) in an editText box. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343637/1397821

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already checked the `Voice Recognition` sample in your `Api demos`, you should go ahead and check it. It should give you a head start. The demos are available in `/android-sdk/samples/...` folder. If you haven't installed them, here is how you may [how to install android api demo app into my phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467835/how-to-install-android-api-demo-app-into-my-phone) .

There are following( any many others) tutorial as well which will help you begin:

1) [Android Voice Recognition Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-voice-recognition-tutorial.html)

2) [Android: Speech To Text using API](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/)

Following might be a good read as well:

[Add Text-To-Speech and Speech Recognition to Your Android Applications](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/add-text-to-speech-and-speech-recognition-to-your-android-applications.html) and [Using the Android Speech Recognition APIs](http://funwithdc.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/using-the-android-speech-recognition-apis/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: NICE! #2 totally worked for me. Funny, because there is already a voice activated microphone icon in our Android phone keyboard. When you are clicking inside an `EditText` in an app, for instance, if you click the mic icon on your keyboard, it will just automatically start dictating your voice to your `EditText`. Doesn't need any code at all! However, not everyone knows about this and explaining it in a sentence would be awkward in the small confines of a UI, so this method works well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your app, you call `startActivityForResult()` using the `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` action. This starts the speech recognition activity, and you can then handle the result in `onActivityResult()`.

```
private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

// Create an intent that can start the Speech Recognizer activity
private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
// Start the activity, the intent will be populated with the speech text
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
}

// This callback is invoked when the Speech Recognizer returns.
// This is where you process the intent and extract the speech text from the intent.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        // Do something with spokenText
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

More info can be found in the [reference](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        myEditText.setText(matches.get(0));
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```